# Styling the list view of Picker class

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am sorry to be asking what seems really obvious question but I've been unable to set the properties (e.g. background color) of the list view / contents when using the picker

The Picker properties style what you see before you expand the list to select contents, but I cannot see or find how to affect the latter

In this example from my XAML the collapsed view of the Picker is styled correctly, but when it opens the background is white / transparent

Sorry, I have looked in many links and just can't find the info

```
        <Picker
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Title="PICKER"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            TitleColor="White"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Style="{StaticResource AlphabetPicker}"
            x:Name="AlphabetPicker" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Alphabet}" 
            SelectedIndexChanged="GetLetterSelected"
            HorizontalOptions="Start">
```

Comment: What platform do you have trouble with, iOS, Android or UWP? A screenshot would be helpful to understand what background you are referring to and in what state the picker is.

Comment: It's both platforms iOS and Android, I know the layouts are different (ioS at foot of page, Android does a popup) for Picker list contents but both show up as white and I wasn't clear on how to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom renderer.

I follow the code in the link: [Customize the Xamarin.Forms Picker Popup List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486310/customize-the-xamarin-forms-picker-popup-list)

MyPicker.cs

```
public class MyPicker : Xamarin.Forms.Picker
{
}
```

MyPickerRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace XamarinDemo.Droid.Renderer
{
class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
    public MyPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    private AlertDialog _dialog;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
            return;

        Control.Click += Control_Click;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Control.Click -= Control_Click;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Picker model = Element;

        var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
        if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
        {
            // set style here
            picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
            picker.MinValue = 0;
            picker.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
            picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
            picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
            picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
        }

        var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        layout.AddView(picker);

        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        builder.SetView(layout);

        builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
        builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel  ", (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
            // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
            Control?.ClearFocus();
            _dialog = null;
        });
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok ", (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
            // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
            if (Element != null)
            {
                if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
            }
            _dialog = null;
        });

        _dialog = builder.Create();
        _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
        {
            ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
        };
        _dialog.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Xaml:

```
     <StackLayout>
        <local:MyPicker x:Name="picker"
    Title="Select a monkey"
    TitleColor="Red">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </local:MyPicker>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: OK well I guess that answers my question that I wasn't missing anything obvious!